How many different combinations of $14$ consecutive days of $30 $ day month are there?
My attempt
$$\sum_{k=14}^{30} (30-14+1)=289$$               where

the many groups of period $k$
can be chosen from $n$ entities

However, I believe I'm wrong here as 289 days appear excessively high. Any hints?

You're summing a constant (i.e. the summand doesn't contain the summation variable), that is probably not right. When it's consecutive days you're interested in you can just select the first.

If I'm not mistaking, there are four months with $30$ days (April, June, September and November). Doesn't that mean that your result should be divisible by four?

The problem statement is a bit ambiguous. I would assume a single month has already been selected and that any given set of day numbers is exactly one combination.
Days $n$ to $n+13$ are one combination of $14$ consecutive days, and the only variation is that $n$ can be as small as $1$ and as large as $17$ (but no larger, because $17+13=30$). Therefore $17$ combinations.
Equivalently, days $m-13$ to $m$ are one combination, $m \geq 14$ because otherwise $m-13$ is less than $1$, and $m \leq 30$ so that $m$ is still a day of a $30$-day month.
Since each $m$ gives you a unique set of $14$ consecutive days, you can sum them up with
$$\sum_{k=14}^{30} 1 = 17. $$
Alternatively, to count the values of $m$ from $14$ to $30$ inclusive, use the formula $30 - 14 + 1 = 17$.
What you have done is to use both methods in one formula.
So you count the $17$ combinations using the non-summation formula $30 - 14 + 1$
and then you repeat this $17$ times using summation notation.
You therefore end up with the square of the desired answer.
In summary, to solve a problem like this:

Choose a single solution method.
Implement that solution method.
Stop.

You overshot step 3.
